# async function not getting result

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am trying to get the result of an async function in my calculateOrderAmount function but it returns undefined.
The console.log in the called function returns the good result, but inside calculateOrderAmount, I get undefined. Here is my code:

```
getMultiStrats = async () => {
    await MultiStrats.findOne({}, (err, multiStrats) => {
        if (err) {
            return err
        }
        if(!multiStrats) {
            return console.log('MultiStrat not found')
        }
        console.log('returns MultiStrat: ' + multiStrats)
        return multiStrats
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

```
async function calculateOrderAmount(balance, ticker){
    const multiState = await StrategyController.getMultiStrats().catch((err) => console.log(err))
    console.log('multiState: ' + multiState)
    some logic
}
```

Here is the console log:

```
multiState: undefined
returns MultiStrat: {
  _id: 5ff73c74d1135b39fc709b80,
  positionsCount: 1,
  inTradeCount: 0,
  __v: 0
}
```

What did I miss? Thanks you very much for your time!

Comment: You're not returning anything from `getMultiStrats()`

Comment: Moreover don't mix async/await with then or callbacks.

Comment: To add some more context to the comment of Pointy. You have `return` statements within the `findOne` callback, but those do return from the callback only, not from the `getMultiStrats` function.

Comment: it leads to some misconception, it works but not a good practice. Follow `async/await` or `thenables` way!

Comment: Thank you very much, I modified the code with var result = await ...
then my function returns the result.
But I'm not sure I get what you are saying(Naren), do you mean if I use async, I shouldn't be using catch()? But instead use try{} catch(e){} ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

The current approach is pretty unclear--there's no need for `.catch`, `async`, `await` all at once. `return multiStrats` returns from the inside of the callback, not from `getMultiStrats`. The `async`/`await` on `getMultiStrats` is superfluous, just adding another promise wrapper that doesn't accomplish anything.

Given that `findOne` as shown here uses a callback rather than a promise, you can either use callbacks all the way or you can promisify `findOne` as follows, using `.then` and `.catch` in the caller:

```js
const MultiStrats = {
  findOne: (obj, cb) => cb(null, "I'm a multistrat!")
};

const StrategyController = {
  getMultiStrats: () => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    MultiStrats.findOne({}, (err, multiStrats) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      else if (multiStrats) {
        return resolve(multiStrats);
      }
    
      reject(Error("Multistrat not found"));
    })
  )
};

const calculateOrderAmount = (balance, ticker) =>
  StrategyController
    .getMultiStrats()
    .then(multiState => {
      console.log('multiState: ' + multiState)
      // some logic
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
;
calculateOrderAmount();
```

Or use `async`/`await` and `try`/`catch`:

```js
const MultiStrats = {
  findOne: (obj, cb) => cb(null, "I'm a multistrat!")
};

const StrategyController = {
  getMultiStrats: () => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    MultiStrats.findOne({}, (err, multiStrats) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      else if (multiStrats) {
        return resolve(multiStrats);
      }
    
      reject(Error("Multistrat not found"));
    })
  )
};

const calculateOrderAmount = async (balance, ticker) => {
  try {
    const multiState = await StrategyController.getMultiStrats();
    console.log('multiState: ' + multiState)
    // some logic
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
calculateOrderAmount();
```

If this is MongoDB's [`findOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/actions/collection.findOne) and already returns a promise, then you can just return the promise to the caller, optionally `await`ing it and throwing for the null result:

```js
const MultiStrats = {
  findOne: async query => "I'm a multistrat!"
};
const StrategyController = {
  getMultiStrats: async () => {
    const result = await MultiStrats.findOne({});
    
    if (result) {
      return result;
    }
    
    throw Error("Multistrat not found");
  }
};

const calculateOrderAmount = (balance, ticker) =>
  StrategyController
    .getMultiStrats()
    .then(multiState => {
      console.log('multiState: ' + multiState);
      // some logic
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
;
calculateOrderAmount();
```

Comment: [`findOne`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOne) returns a [`Query`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html). See [Queries are Not Promises](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises). You code does work fine though, since queries also have a `then` method.

Comment: I have no idea whether OP is using Mongoose or not but thanks for the note. They can add `exec()` but I'm mainly trying to communicate the patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return values from an inner callback and reach the outer function, I would suggest

1- only use promises

2- wrap your code with promise to be sure that `await` will return the `async` result the way you expect to have.

```js
getMultiStrats = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        MultiStrats.findOne({}, (err, multiStrats) => {
            if (err) {
                return err
            }
            if (!multiStrats) {
                console.log('MultiStrat not found')
                reject('MultiStrat not found')
            }
            console.log('returns MultiStrat: ' + multiStrats)
            resolve(multiStrats);
        })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err)
            })

    })
}

async function calculateOrderAmount(balance, ticker) {
    try {
        const multiState = await StrategyController.getMultiStrats()
        console.log('multiState: ' + multiState)
        // some logic
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose). I suggest using the promise interface like described in the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOne).

```
const getMultiStrats = async () => {
    const query = MultiStrats.findOne({});

    let multiStrats;
    try {
        multiStrats = await query.exec();
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }

    if (multiStrats) {    
        console.log("returns MultiStrat: " + multiStrats);    
    } else {
        console.log("MultiStrat not found");
    }
    return multiStrats;
}
```

I would personally not return the error, but instead just let the error be thrown. With the above code the caller of `getMultiStrats` has to figure out if there return value is the expected result or an error. If you don't catch the error, it is thrown further up to the caller.

```
const getMultiStrats = async () => {
    const multiStrats = await MultiStrats.findOne({}).exec();

    if (multiStrats) {    
        console.log("returns MultiStrat: " + multiStrats);    
    } else {
        console.log("MultiStrat not found");
    }
    return multiStrats;
}
```

You can further simplify this if you where to leave the `console.log` of of the equation.

```
const getMultiStrats = () => MultiStrats.findOne({}).exec();
```